# relation between conformal and orthogonal matrices in 2D

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to show that if a matrix $T \in \text{GL}(2, \mathbb{R})$ is conformal, i.e.
$$
\text{arccos} \left( \frac{\langle Tv,Tw \rangle}{|Tv||Tw|} \right) = \text{arccos} \left( \frac{\langle v,w \rangle}{|v||w|} \right),
$$
then there exists a $\lambda > 0$ with $\lambda T \in O(2)$. Starting with an orthogonal matrix and proving the other direction is no problem, but I am a bit lost how to use the equation to show that the matrix is orthogonal.

Answer (score 2):

This proof makes use of some geometry: [Similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_%28geometry%29#Similarity_in_Euclidean_space).

Let $v,w \in \mathbb{R}^2$ be linearly independent vectors. The condition

$$
\text{arccos} \left( \frac{\langle Tv,Tw \rangle}{|Tv||Tw|} \right) 
= 
\text{arccos} \left( \frac{\langle v,w \rangle}{|v||w|} \right) \tag{$1$}
$$

states that the angle $\angle(v,w)$ will be preserved under the linear mapping $T$, i.e.

$$
\angle(v,w) = \angle(Tv,Tw) \tag{$2$}
$$

Now consider the triangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ formed by the vertex triplet $\Delta := (0_{\mathbb{R}2}, v,w)$. Note that $T \in \text{GL}(2, \mathbb{R})$, i.e. $T$ has full rank, and as a result the images of the two linearly independent vectors $v,w$ (these are the two of three sides of the triangle) under the invertible linear map $T$ will be linearly independent again.

This guarantees that the image of our triangle will be a non-degenerate triangle again: the triangle consisting of vertices $\Delta' := (0_{\mathbb{R}^2},Tv,Tw)$.

Making use of the property $(2)$ gives us the similarity of the two triangles $\Delta$ and $\Delta'$. But another property of similar triangles is that the ratios of the lengths of the triangle sides coincide, i.e.

$$
\frac{\lvert v \rvert}{\lvert Tv \rvert} 
=
\frac{ \lvert w \rvert }{\lvert Tw \rvert} 
\quad\left(= \frac{ \lvert (v-w) \rvert}{\lvert T(v-w) \rvert}\right).
$$

This shows that $\lambda := \frac{\lvert v \rvert}{\lvert Tv \rvert} > 0$ is well defined and does not depend on the involved vectors (provided none of them is the zero vector).

Only thing left to do is to show that the mapping $\lambda  T$ is indeed orthogonal, i.e. length preserving. This follows from the bi-linearity of the scalar product and $(1)$:

$$
\langle \lambda Tv, \lambda Tw  \rangle
= 
\lambda^2 \langle Tv, Tw \rangle 
= 
\lambda^2 \langle v,w  \rangle\frac{\lvert Tv \rvert \lvert Tw \rvert }{\lvert v\rvert \lvert w \rvert}
=
\langle v,w \rangle.
$$

Comment: (+1), but "...the three _linearly independent_ vectors $v$, $w$, $v - w$..." should perhaps be "...three _pairwise non-proportional_ vectors..." (since a set of three vectors in a plane isn't linearly independent in the usual sense of linear algebra)...? :)

Comment: @user86418: You are right, a system of three vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is always linearly dependent... I corrected my post.